# TurtleBot Calibration File and Access

Tags: calibration, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to forewarn that I am very new to using the TurtleBot and in general, the linux operating system. I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and running electric.

I have been able to sucuessfully run the calibration process but I immediately become stuck while trying to update old calibration data in order to create a new accurate calibration. I suppose because I am so inexperienced with the TurtleBot, linux and so forth that I am missing something here.

I want to save the new calibration data, but I can't find the correct file to save it on. The ROS tutorial seems overly vague and the command line that it gives

: sudo emacs -nw turtlebot.launch

Does not work. Is this because of my current verison of software?

Essentially, I don't want to update anything on either ubuntu or ROS. I just can't seem to access the correct file path and would appreciate some general tips and direction on this calibration process.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64416/turtlebot-calibration-file-and-access/) by [RobertT](https://answers.ros.org/users/5066/robertt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-06-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can indeed use dynamic reconfigure as a temporary fix, but you would need to do it every time. I also found the tutorial very vague, but I think I found another way to make it work. Find 'turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch' and add (these are my values):

```
<param name="turtlebot_node/gyro_scale_correction" value="1.4074"/>
<param name="turtlebot_node/odom_angular_scale_correction" value="1.0311"/>
<param name="turtlebot_node/gyro_measurement_range" value="250.0"/>
```

Obviously, you then need to start your Turtlebot with minimal.launch. You might need to use "gksudo gedit /pathToMinimalLaunch" to edit the file.

---

Originally posted by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) with karma: 343 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1